# Rails, send data to a facebook app and get this data on my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I know that I need to use the data like this, in order to send data to my facebook canvas app:

```
FB.init({appId: '#{Facebook::APP_ID}', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
FB.ui({  method: 'apprequests', message: 'Invite Friends to Blabloo...',
           data: '{\"draw_token\":\"#{@draw.token}\",\"invitation_token\":\"#{current_kid.invitation_token}\"}',
    exclude_ids: #{@draw.get_invited_ids_for current_kid}},handle_fb_callback);
```

and this send a Facebook invitation, that show you my registration form inside a cavas Facebook app, now on this registration form, on my new action, I need to get this draw_token and invitation_token.

How can I get this information?

NOTE: I'm using the koala gem

Comment: Maybe this will help you out, although the examples are in PHP the logic is the same https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `data` field that you sent is specific for that request you send to the user.

Here are the steps to follow to work with this:

1. When the recipient clicks the requests and redirected to your application with the `request_ids` parameter, you should then get the data for the requests.
2. To get the requests from the user, make the call-

   `{user-id}/apprequests`
3. You will get a **list** of the requests and the **data** for each one (if any).
4. The requests are accumulated and of-course cannot disappear by itself, so you need to **delete** the request once the user has accepted. To delete a request, make the call-

   `/{request-id}?method=delete`

You can see [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/) from the developers site.

Comment: @Jean, did you got the logic?

Comment: Thanks Sahil, but I still don't getting...I send the invitation using my rails apps, the facebook user recive and invitacion y when the user makes click on this invitation, he goes to a url like this https://apps.facebook.com/blabloo_lang_dev/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=385630418244836%2C1484401528439863&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request but what do I have to do on this page to get the value invitation_token that I send using the data attribute on the js

Comment: `he goes to a url like this apps.facebook.com/blabloo_lang_dev/…` - after your this step start with my step-1, then it will make sense to you. (if you'll check this url you wrote- app.facebook.com..., must have `request_ids` appended in the last)

Comment: Sorry But I can make this work...do you have any rails example, because I passing the data using the JS, but now I don't know how to get the data

Comment: Sorry but I didn't got you exactly what you are trying  to say.